# Rails 3:Use of Devise + Doorkeeper for Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my Rails 3 Application i am planing to include Authentication. I saw some post saying Devise + Doorkeeper is the best solution for implementing Authentication in Rails 3.

What is the use of Devise + Doorkeeper in Rails Application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You dont need doorkeeper unless you plan to expose some kind of API and require OAuth for that API. Doorkeeper is used for Oauth, and it's a rails engine just like devise, but they are completely different gems.